# Сервер не дает ответ

Tags: c, сокет

Есть следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void error(char *message){
    puts(message);
    exit(1);
}

int open_listener_socket(){
    int listener_d = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(listener_d == -1)
        error("Can't open socket!");
    return listener_d;
}

void bind_to_port(int socket, int port){
    struct sockaddr_in name;
    name.sin_family = PF_INET;
    name.sin_port = (in_port_t) htons(port);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    int reuse = 1;
    if(setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(int)) == -1)
        error("Can't set reuse option for socket!");
    int c = bind(socket, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name));
    if(c == -1)
        error("Can't bind the socket!");
}

int say(int socket, char *message){
    int result = send(socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
    if(result == -1)
        error("Can't send the message to the socket!");
    return result;
}

int read_in(int socket, char *buf, int len){
    char *s = buf;
    int slen = len;
    int c = recv(socket, s, slen, 0);
    while((c > 0) && (s[c - 1] != '\n')){
        s += c;
        slen -= c;
        c = recv(socket, s, slen, 0);
    }
    if(c < 0)
        return c;
    else if(c == 0)
        buf[0] = '0';
    else
        s[c - 1] = '\0';
    return len - slen;
}

int main(){
    int socket = open_listener_socket();
    bind_to_port(socket, 30000);

    if(listen(socket, 10) == -1)
        printf("Can't listen the port!");

    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    unsigned int address_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    int connect_d = accept(socket, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &address_size);
    if(connect_d == -1)
        printf("Can't open the second socket!");

    say(socket, "Hello world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Это код сервера.

Он компилируется, запускается.
При запуске ничего не происходит, что и логично, accept ждет.

В другом терминале я ввожу telnet 127.0.0.1 30000, порт - 30000.
Однако я не получаю hello world на экран, просто закрываеться коннект, в чем проблема?

Comment: Hint: `perror()` или `err()` вместо вашего колеса.

Comment: @Oandri В чем же ошибка, может подскажите?

Comment: Может поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194961/how-do-i-use-setsockoptso-reuseaddr

Comment: @Oandriy проблема в том, что нет эрроров, он просто не пашет, не передает сообщение, а оканьчивает работу, все.

Comment: Запустите `netstat -nap -t`, `ss`,  `tcpdump` до, во время и после. Так может научитесь дебажить сетевые программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаем man 2 accept:

**DESCRIPTION**

*The  accept()  system call is used with connection-based socket types (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET).  It extracts the first connection request on the queue of pending  connections  for  the  listening  socket, sockfd, creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file descriptor referring to that socket.  The newly created socket is not in the listening state.  The original socket sockfd is  unaffected  by  this call.8*

Понятно? Этот вызов создаёт НОВЫЙ сокет connect_fd, которым и нужно пользоваться.

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно!